# Statistical significance tests for neural networks

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neural-networks, asymptotics

[Horel & Giesecke 2020](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume21/19-264/19-264.pdf) developed a statistical signficance test for feature variables in a single-layer feedforward neural network. Namely, fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, let $Y\in\mathbb{R}$ be a dependent variable, let $X\in\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be feature variables with distribution $P$, and consider a regression model:
\begin{equation}
Y=f_0(X)+\epsilon.
\end{equation}
Here, $f_0:\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an unknown and deterministic regressor and $\epsilon\sim (0, \sigma^2)$ is idiosyncratic error, where the regressor belongs to the function space
$$\Theta=\left\{f\in\mathcal{C}^1, f:\mathcal{X}\subset \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}, ||f||_{\lfloor \frac{d}{2}\rfloor + 2}\le B \right\}$$
for $B$ a constant.

Since we are interested in the effect of variable $X_j$ on $Y$, we observe if $\frac{\partial f_0(x)}{\partial x_j}=0$ for all $x\in \mathcal{X}$, then the $j$-th variable does not have an influence on the response. They propose a significance test:
\begin{align*}
&H_0: \lambda_j=\int_{\mathcal{X}} \left(\frac{\partial f_0(x)}{\partial x_j}\right)^2 d\mu(x)=0,\\
&H_A: \lambda_j\ne 0,
\end{align*}
where $\mu$ is a positive measure. When $\mu=P$, i.e. the law of feature space $X$, the statistic is
\begin{equation}
\lambda_j = \mathbb{E}\left[\Bigg(\frac{\partial f_0(x)}{\partial x_j}\Bigg)^2\right].
\end{equation}

Let $f_n$ be an estimator of $f$ trained on $n$ i.i.d. samples of $(Y,X)$. Then the test statistic is
\begin{equation}
\lambda_j^n =\int_{\mathcal{X}}\left(\frac{\partial f_n(x)}{\partial x_j}\right)^2 d\mu(x).
\end{equation}

The paper studies the asymptotic distribution of $\lambda_j^n$ as $n\to\infty$, where it is assumed that the hidden dimension $K_n$ of the network grows with $n$. Theorem 1 shows that $f_n$ converges weakly in the metric space $(\Theta, d)$ for $d(f,g)=\mathbb{E}[(f-g)^2]$ such that
\begin{equation}
r_n(f_n-f_0)\implies h^*
\end{equation}
for $h^*$ the argmax of the Gaussian process ${\mathbb{G}_f:f\in\Theta}$ with mean zero and covariance $Cov(\mathbb{G}_s, \mathbb{G}_t)=4\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}_X(s(X)t(X))$ and $r_n=\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)^{(d+1)/(2(2d+1))}$. Under the assumptions of Theorem 1 and the null $H_0$, they find:

\begin{equation}
r_n^2\lambda_j^n \implies \int_{\mathcal{X}} \left(\frac{\partial h^*(x)}{\partial x_j}\right)^2 d\mu(x).
\end{equation}

In section 4, they use the fact that $\Theta$ is a subspace of the Hilbert space $$L^2(P):=\left\{f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}: ||f||_{L^2(P)} <\infty\right\}$$ to admit an orthonormal basis and are able to obtain a series representation of the asymptotic distribution.

**Is there a generalized version of the convergence property in Theorem 1 for a neural network with an arbitrary number of layers? If not, is there a known/standard method for statistical significance testing of feature variables for neural networks?**